# How can I set an intent's class from every each from string item that was clicked

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to start another intent from every single item that was clicked and
also please tell me where should i put your solution code 

Here are the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;

// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Listview Data
    String products[] = {"Dell", "HTC ","iPhone ", "Samsung Galaxy"};

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name,products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

         @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
         // When user changed the Text
         Identifikasi1.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
     }

     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
             int arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }

 });
 }
```

i'm still beginner and have no idea to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should implements `onItemClickListener` and set intent in listener method `onItemClick()`
For example:

```
public void MainActivity extends Activity implements onItemClickListener{
   //your code
  //...
```

@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,long id) {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
 }
}

Comment: actually the "implements" is not working for me, but i can set the "onItemClickListener" like this "lisview.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()" and place the @Override with all public void + intent code below it and how ever it works...really big help...thanks . Sorry for my bad English